# Why local reference is updated only if there is an event bound to the element

Tags: angular

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:
      `<input #data (input)="f()" />
      {{ data.value }}`
})
export class AppComponent {

  f() {}
}
```

i am able to get `data.value` using the above code snippet, but when i remove `(input)="f()"` part from input element, `data.value` is no longer getting updated when i type in input element

Comment: Please do not do this to use the HTML template to write in the TS file.
Write it in .html

Comment: @ZhuniqiA i did this just for the sake of this question so it's easier to see whole code. otherwise i always use a separate .html file

Comment: @ZhuniqiA There's nothing wrong with doing that - if you're template is small then why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the data by using [Angular Two-Way data binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel-two-way-binding)

For you example this would be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:
      `<input [(ngModel)]="input" />
      {{ input }}`
})
export class AppComponent {

  public input: string = '';
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gchfdb

This has to be done because Angular Change Detection is [based on events, XHR and Timers](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html). If no listeners are attached to the input no events will be fired, thus the template will not be evaluated.

Modifying the value through `Input()` or any other Action would trigger the ChangeDetection.

(Bad Practice: You can also run [Change Detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829089/9277073) via `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.)

Comment: i know two way binding would solve this, but i am still curious about why local reference works the way i mentioned in the question